# How do i align items in a list to look like a chat

Tags: css, vue.js

[Vue chat application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahkci.png)

I'm creating this chat app like a little project, but I can't make the messages align properly. The messages sent by the user (light blue) should be on the right side, the CSS looks like:

```
.received {
   text-align: left;
   background-color: #0A2472;
   margin: 1%;
   color: white;
   padding: 1%;
   max-width: fit-content;
}

.sent {
  text-align: right;
  align-content: right;
  background-color: #A6E1FA;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  max-width: fit-content;
}
```

It looks fine, until "max-width: fit-content" is added to the style.
Any solutions or other approaches?

Comment: its better you post html as well or try to create demo

Comment: What happens when you put `margin-right: auto;` in `.received` and `margin-left:auto;` in `.sent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your messages are only as wide as their text, so the alignment doesn't matter.

I made a container to hold them. I like [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for laying out almost everything. The chat messages are just rows in the grid, some justified left and some right.

```css
.chatboard {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 0.6rem;
  max-width: 40rem;
}

.sent,
.received {
  padding: 1%;
  min-width: 20rem;
  border-radius: 0.6rem;
}

.received {
  justify-self: left;
  background-color: #0A2472;
  color: white;
}

.sent {
  text-align: right;
  justify-self: right;
  align-content: right;
  background-color: #A6E1FA;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatboard">
  <div class="received">Hi there</div>
  <div class="sent">Hello there</div>
  <div class="received">Hi there</div>
  <div class="sent">Hello there</div>
  <div class="received">Hi there</div>
  <div class="sent">Hello there</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of how you can achieve this. I will paste the code below. Look in the css for the specific style you want. It looks like the style rules would be the style modifying the `<p>` tag in the example the specific css rules modifying it are

```
display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
```

here is the html

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3 class=" text-center">Messaging</h3>
<div class="messaging">
      <div class="inbox_msg">
        <div class="inbox_people">
          <div class="headind_srch">
            <div class="recent_heading">
              <h4>Recent</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="srch_bar">
              <div class="stylish-input-group">
                <input type="text" class="search-bar"  placeholder="Search" >
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="button"> <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
                </span> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="inbox_chat">
            <div class="chat_list active_chat">
              <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5>Sunil Rajput <span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5>
                  <p>Test, which is a new approach to have all solutions 
                    astrology under one roof.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat_list">
              <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5>Sunil Rajput <span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5>
                  <p>Test, which is a new approach to have all solutions 
                    astrology under one roof.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat_list">
              <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5>Sunil Rajput <span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5>
                  <p>Test, which is a new approach to have all solutions 
                    astrology under one roof.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat_list">
              <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5>Sunil Rajput <span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5>
                  <p>Test, which is a new approach to have all solutions 
                    astrology under one roof.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat_list">
              <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5>Sunil Rajput <span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5>
                  <p>Test, which is a new approach to have all solutions 
                    astrology under one roof.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat_list">
              <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5>Sunil Rajput <span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5>
                  <p>Test, which is a new approach to have all solutions 
                    astrology under one roof.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat_list">
              <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5>Sunil Rajput <span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5>
                  <p>Test, which is a new approach to have all solutions 
                    astrology under one roof.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mesgs">
          <div class="msg_history">
            <div class="incoming_msg">
              <div class="incoming_msg_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
              <div class="received_msg">
                <div class="received_withd_msg">
                  <p>Test which is a new approach to have all
                    solutions</p>
                  <span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    June 9</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outgoing_msg">
              <div class="sent_msg">
                <p>Test which is a new approach to have all
                  solutions</p>
                <span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    June 9</span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="incoming_msg">
              <div class="incoming_msg_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
              <div class="received_msg">
                <div class="received_withd_msg">
                  <p>Test, which is a new approach to have</p>
                  <span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    Yesterday</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="outgoing_msg">
              <div class="sent_msg">
                <p>Apollo University, Delhi, India Test</p>
                <span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    Today</span> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="incoming_msg">
              <div class="incoming_msg_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
              <div class="received_msg">
                <div class="received_withd_msg">
                  <p>We work directly with our designers and suppliers,
                    and sell direct to you, which means quality, exclusive
                    products, at a price anyone can afford.</p>
                  <span class="time_date"> 11:01 AM    |    Today</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="type_msg">
            <div class="input_msg_write">
              <input type="text" class="write_msg" placeholder="Type a message" />
              <button class="msg_send_btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <p class="text-center top_spac"> Design by <a target="_blank" href="#">Sunil Rajput</a></p>
```

here is the css

```
.container{max-width:1170px; margin:auto;}
img{ max-width:100%;}
.inbox_people {
  background: #f8f8f8 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40%; border-right:1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
.inbox_msg {
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.top_spac{ margin: 20px 0 0;}


.recent_heading {float: left; width:40%;}
.srch_bar {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 60%; padding:
}
.headind_srch{ padding:10px 29px 10px 20px; overflow:hidden; border-bottom:1px solid #c4c4c4;}

.recent_heading h4 {
  color: #05728f;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin: auto;
}
.srch_bar input{ border:1px solid #cdcdcd; border-width:0 0 1px 0; width:80%; padding:2px 0 4px 6px; background:none;}
.srch_bar .input-group-addon button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  padding: 0;
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.srch_bar .input-group-addon { margin: 0 0 0 -27px;}

.chat_ib h5{ font-size:15px; color:#464646; margin:0 0 8px 0;}
.chat_ib h5 span{ font-size:13px; float:right;}
.chat_ib p{ font-size:14px; color:#989898; margin:auto}
.chat_img {
  float: left;
  width: 11%;
}
.chat_ib {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  width: 88%;
}

.chat_people{ overflow:hidden; clear:both;}
.chat_list {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 18px 16px 10px;
}
.inbox_chat { height: 550px; overflow-y: scroll;}

.active_chat{ background:#ebebeb;}

.incoming_msg_img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6%;
}
.received_msg {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 92%;
 }
 .received_withd_msg p {
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #646464;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
.time_date {
  color: #747474;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
}
.received_withd_msg { width: 57%;}
.mesgs {
  float: left;
  padding: 30px 15px 0 25px;
  width: 60%;
}

 .sent_msg p {
  background: #05728f none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0; color:#fff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 12px;
  width:100%;
}
.outgoing_msg{ overflow:hidden; margin:26px 0 26px;}
.sent_msg {
  float: right;
  width: 46%;
}
.input_msg_write input {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  font-size: 15px;
  min-height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
}

.type_msg {border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4;position: relative;}
.msg_send_btn {
  background: #05728f none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 11px;
  width: 33px;
}
.messaging { padding: 0 0 50px 0;}
.msg_history {
  height: 516px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```